# Why does my computer have active ports if it isn't a server?

Tags: server, port

As I know, only servers have active ports, but when doing "netstat -a" in command prompt there are actually many listening ports in my computer which is not a server.  Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

One reason at least is that you'll have TCP connections open to servers on the Internet and both sides of the connection (client as well as server) have a port associated with them.

You could show us the lines from `netstat` and point out which ones, in particular, you're concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

> As I know, only servers have active ports ...

That is incorrect knowledge.

- Most non-server computers will have one or more local system services listening on the loopback IP address; e.g. 127.0.0.1 if you are using IPv4.  Examples of such services include SMTP and SYSLOG.
- Some operating systems enable ports to allow remote access or remote debugging.
- Some applications work by providing a local HTTP service which the user can connect to using a conventional or embedded web browser.
- Some applications work by connecting to a local database via the loopback IP address.  The local database service will be listening.
- Some application protocols (e.g. classic FTP) use a reverse connection from server to client.  In FTP this is referred to as "active mode".
- And so on.

In short, there are lots of situations where a non-server machine will need to listen for network connections on either local or external ports.

The notion of a "server" is far more nuanced than your "knowledge".  And the `netstat -a` output is (probably<sup>1</sup>) demonstrating that.

---

<sup>1 - It is also possible that you have unwanted entries in the `netstat -a`; i.e. local services or applications that *shouldn't* be listening for incoming connection.  But we can only distinguish the "good" and "bad" on a case-by-case basis.</sup>